# Can I make a Maven plugin that generates a project and then builds that project?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Is it possible to combine the capabilities of an archetype and a normal Maven plugin into a single plugin?

I have a custom language which I can compile into Java source code.  I've written a Maven plugin which does this in the `generate-sources` phase, adds the Java source to the project, and builds the project.  It works as I'd expect.

However, to use it, I need to first write out a `pom.xml` file referencing my plugin and describing where the input files live.  I'd like to be able to go straight from raw input files to compiled code in a single maven command.

For example, suppose I have this directory structure:

```
my-project/
    some-input-file.dsl
```

I want to run

```
bash$ mvn com.waisbrot.plugin:generate -DgroupID=com.waisbrot package
```

and after Maven's done running have:

```
my-project/
    some-input-file.dsl
    pom.xml
    target/
        generated-sources/
            plugin/
                SomeInputFile.java
        classes/
            com/
                waisbrot/
                    SomeInputFile.class
        some-input-file-1.0.jar
```

Comment: The best thing is to configure your plugin into the lifecycle within the pom you've shown. That's it. The location of your dsl file should be changed like src/main/name-of-your-dsl/xyz-input-file.dsl. Like other DSL are handled with Maven like Groovy etc.

Comment: The file could be moved and its new location stored in the generated POM; I don't care about that. What I'm asking is if I can transform a non-Maven directory into a Maven project and then in the same breath execute a maven goal on that newly-created project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the integration testing of the archetype allows you to declare the parameter and goals. So do this:

1. Pick the template project you want to create
2. mvn archetype:create-from-project. It will create a new archetype
3. Review src/test/resources/projects, especially goal.txt and archetype.properties (source: http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html). Tweak so install will be implicity
4. mvn verify will be able to build the archetype, run the it, and get it installed

Hope it helps

Comment: Well it appears that I'm asking for something totally unsupported by Maven.  This is probably the closest I'll be able to get and looks like a pretty nifty kludge.  Thanks!

Comment: It helps if you split your functionality into several @Mojos, each one by default bound to a lifecycle phase.